# No export sam found error when using windbg

Tags: debugging, dll, windbg

I have attached windbg to an application, I then inject a simple .dll which I made.

I use the line

> lm

The output is

> 259b0000 259e5000   Project (deferred)

I then use

> 0:046> !SaveModule 259b0000 c:\Users\name\Documents\pleasework.dll

With the error:

> No export sam found

Could someone please suggest a way to fix this error. Thank you

*Edit*
I made a really stupid mistake I forgot to load SOS.dll
I do this then after entering the !sam or !SaveModule command I get this error

> Extension commands need clr.dll in order to have something to do.

I try all the sxe ld clr etc. I enter "g" it doesn't break automatically so I break it myself then still get this

> .loadby sos clr
>
> Unable to find module 'clr'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.loadby not work, but .load works well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929496/loadby-not-work-but-load-works-well)

Comment: Are you sure you're debugging a .NET application? What does '!lmi clr' show? If not found, what does '!lmi mscorwks' show? The former module is for later versions of .NET and the latter is for earlier versions.

Comment: Marc is exactly right.  Run those two commands, and if they do not show either as loaded in the target, then no runtime has been initialized. With no .NET runtime in the target, SOS has no point.

Comment: @SteveJohnson: well, `!sam` as long as it only saves a DLL could be potentially useful.

Comment: @Thomas: That's true, but I think SOS always looks for a runtime in its extension init.