# Windbg .load extension wants an escaped backslash (\) character in the path

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg, sos

When I try to load an extension such as sos or psscor4 using the `.load` commmand in Windbg, it exhibits a behavior I did not expect. So, may be it is just a matter of setting my expectation right as to this behavior being normal.

For example, when I say:

```
0:00> .load "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll"
```

It complains as follows:

> The call to
>   LoadLibrary(C:WindowsMicrosoft.NETFramework64v4.0.30319sos.dll)
>   failed, Win32 error 0n2
>       "The system cannot find the file specified." Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.

I infer that it is expecting me to escape the backslash.

However, when I escape the backslash character like so, it works just fine and loads the extension.

```
0:00> .load "C:\\Windows\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\sos.dll"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loads fine without quotation marks

```
0:00> .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
```

even if the path contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Hi use look like this

```
@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll"
```

hope it help

Comment: I know I can do that. The question is not "what should I do?" The question is -- is that the right behavior? Or is there a setting where it recognizes a single backslash?

Comment: Thank you. Please let me cross-validate that assertion because the source of my confusion and of asking this question is -- I recall vaguely that all the Windbg demos I watched loaded this with a single backslash. Can't remember, though, if they said `@` (fixed literal).

Comment: Look! This guy runs it without escaping the backslashes. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25929496/303685

Comment: Thank you so much for the alternative.